# View Missing Numbers in a Sequence by date

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table name "Numerator" has 3 columns: No_Fact, Numerat and Date. Like this:

```
No_Fact         Numerat         Date
1207020015      000713          2012-07-02 00:00:00.000
1207020016      000720          2012-07-02 00:00:00.000
1207020017      000722          2012-07-02 00:00:00.000
1207020019      000723          2012-07-02 00:00:00.000
1207020022      000724          2012-07-02 00:00:00.000
1207020021      000733          2012-07-02 00:00:00.000
1207020020      000734          2012-07-02 00:00:00.000
1207020018      000735          2012-07-02 00:00:00.000
1208120001      000766          2012-08-12 00:00:00.000
1208120002      000769          2012-08-12 00:00:00.000
1208230001      000777          2012-08-23 00:00:00.000
1208230002      000780          2012-08-23 00:00:00.000
```

I want to view some missing numbers between numbers inside Numerat column, so I have tried using the code that is:

```
SELECT A.Numerat+1 AS 'MISSING FROM', MIN(B.Numerat)-1 AS 'TO'
FROM Numerator A, Numerator B
WHERE A.Numerat < B.Numerat
GROUP BY A.Numerat
HAVING A.Numerat+1 < MIN(B.Numerat)
ORDER BY 1
```

And result set:

```
MISSING FROM   TO
714            719 
721            721
725            732
736            765
767            768
770            776
778            779
```

This is a code that nice.
But the sequence numbers is too many, to be incompatible with the need to be concise. So I only want to show part rows today (2012-08-23) only, likes this:

```
MISSING FROM   TO
778            779
```

I am very grateful to anyone who can decode it, Thank You.

There's an interesting thing when the next line in the insert in the table,
I show began on August 23 2012:

```
No_Fact         Numerat         Date
1208230001      000777          2012-08-23 00:00:00.000
1208230002      000780          2012-08-23 00:00:00.000
1208250001      000782          2012-08-25 00:00:00.000
1208250002      000783          2012-08-25 00:00:00.000
1208250003      000784          2012-08-25 00:00:00.000
1208250004      000785          2012-08-25 00:00:00.000
1208250005      000786          2012-08-25 00:00:00.000
1208250006      000788          2012-08-25 00:00:00.000
1208250007      000789          2012-08-25 00:00:00.000
1208250008      000790          2012-08-25 00:00:00.000
1208250009      000793          2012-08-25 00:00:00.000
1208250010      000794          2012-08-25 00:00:00.000
```

As my original purpose, that I want to see the missing numbers in the Numerat column and to summarily I only just wanted to show a line I enter this day alone, then with advice from bluefeet I use the following code:

```
SELECT A.Numerat+1 AS 'MISSING FROM', MIN(B.Numerat)-1 AS 'TO'
FROM Numerator A
INNER JOIN Numerator B
  ON A.Numerat < B.Numerat
  AND a.Tanggal = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GetDate()), 0)
GROUP BY A.Numerat
HAVING A.Numerat+1 < MIN(B.Numerat)
ORDER BY 1
```

and achieving results:

```
MISSING FROM   TO
787            787
791            792
```

If we look carefully there is a missing number that does not appear, that is:

```
MISSING FROM   TO
781            781
```

But we do not know exactly, including the date do it? Is 23 or 25. In this case it is not important to know exactly falls on what the date this missing number, obviously there is one number missing, it should be noted, and due on the 24th of all public holidays, let us enter it on the 25th. Can anyone help?

Comment: If it's always the latest row you need, you can surround the current statement with `SELECT MAX([Missing From]), MAX(To) FROM (<yourEntireStatementWithoutOrderBy>) m`

Comment: @sqlcollector do you want to limit your records by the date meaning you want to see all gaps for a specific date or do you just want the most recent gap for the most recent date?

Comment: bluefeet.-I pondered your question;
@sqlcollector do you want to limit your records by the date meaning you want to see all gaps for a specific date or do you just want the most recent gap for the most recent date? - Bluefeet.
if you can replace it with another sentence structure or diagram? Especially the "most recent gap" and "most recent date", I am very novice at all right now, thank you.

Comment: @sqlcollector I mean do you want all gaps for a day, meaning on 7/2/2012 you would return several rows of data? Or do you want only one record, the last gap for the date?

Comment: thanks bluefeet, I understand because I see there is a missing number but cannot look good on earlier or later date. So I want all gaps for a day - sqlcollector

Comment: bluefeet, I have been getting all the missing numbers, but the data is too long because of so large.  So I want to limit it to just one day of data is the last day that I input.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few different ways to do this query, all have incorporated the date into it:

```
SELECT A.Numerat+1 AS 'MISSING FROM', MIN(B.Numerat)-1 AS 'TO'
FROM test A
INNER JOIN test B
  ON A.Numerat < B.Numerat
  AND a.dt = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GetDate()), 0)
GROUP BY A.Numerat
HAVING A.Numerat+1 < MIN(B.Numerat)
ORDER BY 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ab3a/7)

Or

```
;with cte as
(
  select numerat, dt, 
    row_number() over(partition by dt order by numerat) rn
  from test
  where dt = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GetDate()), 0)
)
select c.Numerat+1 MissingFrom, t.Numerat-1 [To]
from cte c
inner join test t
  on c.Numerat < t.Numerat
where c.rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ab3a/16)

Or you can use a `MAX()` aggregate with no date:

```
SELECT max([Missing From]), max([to])
FROM
(
  SELECT A.Numerat+1 AS 'MISSING FROM', MIN(B.Numerat)-1 AS 'TO'
  FROM test A
  INNER JOIN test B
    ON A.Numerat < B.Numerat
  GROUP BY A.Numerat
  HAVING A.Numerat+1 < MIN(B.Numerat)
) x
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ab3a/19)

Comment: The date dependant statements fail when there are more than 2 records for a given date *(ex. 2012-07-02)*.

Comment: @Lieven true, but it also depends on what they want, do they only want the most recent gap for a specific day or do they want to limit the records by day. It is hard to tell given they are only showing two dates for `2012-08-23`

Comment: @sqlcollector if you have additional questions or details, please edit your original question instead of editing an answer to ask it

Comment: @sqlcollector I have seen your edit it is not exactly clear what your requirement is.  Do you want to see the missing numbers by date or a list of all missing numbers?  When you specify a date the missing value should show-- see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99c4e/9)